# "Could not get any response" in Postman instead of the ModelState error in XML format when sending BadRequest(ModelState)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Forgive my ignorance, this is my first attempt at an ASP.Net Core WebAPI.  I'm using AspNetCore.MVC 1.1.4 in case that's relevant.  I am using Postman to test my API.

I have a simple HttpPost which sends back the expected 400 Bad Request. For this test, I am sending malformed XML so my hostMessage doesn't deserialize correctly.  The customer wants all the messages sent and received in XML.

```
[HttpPost("Message")]
public IActionResult ReceiveMessage([FromBody] HostMessage hostMessage)
{
    if (hostMessage == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

This gets me a nice expected response.
[image: Valid expected Bad Request]
When I change the code so that it will return the error.

```
[HttpPost("Message")]
public IActionResult ReceiveMessage([FromBody] HostMessage hostMessage)
{
    if (hostMessage == null)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

I was expecting to get a Status 400 Bad Request with the exception found in the Model State (There was an error deserializing the object) but instead, I get the "Could not get any response"

Model State Error:
[image: Model State Error expected]

Actual Postman Response:
[image: Actual Postman Response]

So the question is, why when I add the ModelState to the Bad Request it no longer returns an expected Bad Request with the error, but instead just says it can't get any response.

**Pre Post Edit?**
Okay figured out while writing this post.  The client wants everything in XML. My configure services are set up like this.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddMvcOptions(x => x.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new XmlDataContractSerializerInputFormatter()))
        .AddMvcOptions(x => x.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter()));
}
```

And when I remove the OutputFormatter, I get the expected output in JSON.
[image: expected out, but in json]

So I've updated my question title and am now asking how I can return the expected ModelState error in XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your specific question about how to get that Error Message, you'd need to traverse the `ModelStateDictionary` object down to the `Errors` Exception collection and get the first Exception's message as shown in your object tree in the picture.

If that's what you're after, I would suggest making an extension method of the `ModelStateDictionary` to do the searching for you and return the messages you want. Assuming that is all you want from the ModelState and that you might want more than one message if they exist, I would try this:

```
    public static List<string> FindErrors(this ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        List<string> errors = new List<string>();
        foreach (var value in modelState.Values)
        {
            foreach(var error in value.Errors)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(error.ErrorMessage))
                    errors.Add(error.ErrorMessage);

                if (error.Exception != null)
                    errors.Add(error.Exception.ToString()); // The ToString method gets the message you were looking for in this example
            }
        }

        return errors;
    }
```

To then be used like this:
`return BadRequest(ModelState.FindErrors());`

If the Exception messages are really what you're after, this should get you what you need.